# Какой род у слова "суши"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Какого рода в русском языке слово "суши"? То есть, "один суши", "одно суши" или "одна суши"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари (Лопатин) рекомендуют среднего, несклоняемое. Одно суши.

Answer (score 0):

Суши  - среднего рода, по общему правилу - несклоняемые заимствованные существительные,если они неодушевленные, относятся к среднему роду. Впрочем, из этого правила много исключений, например "салями", "брокколи" и др.

Comment: Это весьма сомнительное правило, если оно вообще существует.
Ту гораздо актуальнее то, что такие слова наследуют грамматический род от родового слова.  
Суши - блюдо - оно.  
Салями - колбаса - она.  
и т.д.

Comment: Правило существует. См. учебники по культуре речи. И даже в школьных учебниках есть. Именно поэтому "бра" - среднего рода (хотя лампа), пальто - среднего (хотя одежда). По родовому слову определяется род  неизменяемых существительных, обозначающих географические названия. 
Вот отсюда и пошло... По ассоциации с родовым понятием "салями" - "колбаса", "авеню" - "улица", "кольраби" - капуста  -  стали женского рода, хинди - язык, сулугуни - сыр  - мужского. Список исключений конечен и приводится в пособиях по морфологии и культуре речи.

Comment: Возможно, с течением времени правило изменится, но пока оно есть.

Comment: Вы уже убедили, что правила - именно правила - нет. ;)
Поскольку существует оно только в школьных учебниках.
Можно понапридумывать очень много "правил" - и объявить всё, что не по правилам, исключениями. Конечность списка - не аргумент. Число слов языке тоже конечно. 

Давайте все-таки согласимся с тем, что "конечно" скорее число немотивированных ни родовым словом, ни графическим или фонетическим обликом слова случаев использования среднего рода.  
 
Пальто изначально было мужского рода, стало средним под влиянием характерного "окончения". То же сейчас происходит и с кофе.

Comment: Читайте внимательно! Я сказала - в пособиях по культуре речи и ДАЖЕ в школьном учебнике. Под рукой всех нет, но (все-таки пошла я к шкафу!)Розенталя и его "Справочник по литературной правке", "Словарь трудностей", "Практическая стилистика" (Вузовские преподаватели на филфаках не перестали его любить), из новых пособий - Савко И. Русский язык. Правильность речи. А "Словарь грамматических трудностей" РАН Института русского языка им. Виноградова М.,2007 год для Вас убедителен?

Comment: Цитирую:" Наименования неодушевленных предметов чаще всего относятся к существительным среднего рода...
ОТСТУПЛЕНИЯ ОТ ЭТОГО ОБЩЕГО ПРАВИЛА и колебания в родовом оформлении наблюдаются прежде всего в тех случаях ..."( и дальше снова про салями, биенале и др.)
Конечно, уже не так категорично, вместо слова - исключения теперь просто "отступления",  но я об этом и говорила (с течением времени правило изменится)